# Cold water faucet now runs very warm, but not quite hot

Tags: water, faucet

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my bathroom faucet.  The hot water side runs hot like it should, but the cold water side no longer runs cold.  It's *very* warm.  None of the other bathrooms in my house act like this.  In addition, I believe it was around the same time that the handle is now quite hard to turn.  Can anyone explain how this could happen?

Comment: Is the faucet a single handle, or separate handles for hot and cold?

Comment: Has anything changed? e.g. did you recently install the plumbing, and inadvertently put the hot pipe too close to the cold pipe?

Comment: They are separate faucets.  They have been installed for over a year and nothing has changed.  It really makes no sense.  Perhaps what I should do is let the water run for a really long time, but capture the water so I can give it to the plants later and not be wasteful.  :)  I have run it for about 30 seconds, but honestly cold water should just be cold as soon as you turn it on.

Comment: Man, it's got to be a time of day thing, which I hadn't noticed before.  Maybe the pipe running to this bathroom gets hot from it being warm out in the afternoon?  It's now evening and the temperature is pretty normal again.

Comment: Do you have another single handle fixture nearby, like a shower? The mixing valve on these can fail and allow warm water to pass through the valve to the cold side.

Comment: I have separates, so that's not likely the problem.  I really think it must be heat getting to the pipe and maybe I didn't notice it before.  Or maybe this is a sign that I should go under the house and look for possible trouble.  :)